# Issue on Redirecting Projects on WampServer Index Page

Tags: wampserver

Using WampServer 2.5 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit I am not able to redirect from Wamp index page to Projects URL. For example, I have a Project called "Proj 1" which listed under "**Your Projects**" but when I click on that the address bar only change to

> Proj 1

and I get this error message on page **Oops! Google Chrome could not find Proj 1**

and when I add localhost/ to the URL inbox it works fine. I tried to re install the Wamp several times but it didn't fix the issue.
Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **QUICK AND DIRTY** way to revert back to the old way and undo this new **INTENDED** functionality is:-

Edit \wamp\index.php

Find this line at aprox line 34

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

And change it to

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

**CORRECT Solution**

Is to create a VirtualHost for each of your projects that you want to store under the `\wamp\www\` folder. Or anywhere else for that matter.

Edit the file `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

*change version number to match your installed version of apache*

Remove its default contents and add this to define your first VirtualHost definition

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName proj1
   DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/proj1
   <Directory "C:/wamp/www/proj1/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
      Require local
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save it!

Now edit the httpd.conf file ( using the wampmanager menu links ) and uncomment the line that includes the file we have just changed.

Find

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And remove the `#` comment character like so :-

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Now edit the HOSTS file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add a new line to tell windows that there is a site called `proj1` so it should end up looking like this :-

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost

127.0.0.1 proj1
::1       proj1
```

Remember you have to be an Administrator to edit the hosts file!!! Hit the Windows key, type note, right click on Notepad and choose `Run as Administrator`.

Now to apply that change to the HOSTS file either reboot or

Start a command window using "Run as Administrator" and run these 2 commands :-

```
net stop Dnscache
net start Dnscache
```

This will refresh the windows DNS cache, and you new site will be addressable.

Now last of all restart the Apache service so it picks up your new VirtualHost definition.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart service
```

**PS**: Remove the space from the "proj 1" folder name. Spaces can cause odd issues. Remember Apache was ported from Unix and Unix does not really like spaces in directory names.

Comment: This answer, for all intents and purposes, may be correct, but it is a painful one. I'm not sure for what benefit such a "feature" was added to WAMP, but I liked how everything "just worked" before, and the quick and dirty fix seems like the closest thing to the old way.

Comment: Its not a WAMPServer feature its an Apache feature and has been there for years. WampServer is just encoraging users to make good use of it so that projects they develop will transfer to live servers without the issues that they have if you develop in `\wamp\www\project` using the default `DocumentRoot` of `\wamp\www`. It adds immense flexibility as well, as you can configure each VHOST for its specific requirements without effecting other projects. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482 Once you have created your first VHOST the next is just a copy/paste/change directory name process.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be updating the www index.php (Line 338) from

```
$projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.($suppress_localhost ? 'http://' : '').$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

to

```
$projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.($suppress_localhost ? 'http://localhost/' : '').$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

Comment: This of course works but is a VERY BAD Solution and should not be done. See my answer for a Quick and Dirty solution and also the Correct solution.